# .htaccess RewriteRule prevents directory access

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

I had to modify my .htaccess file when I added the 'vanity URL' feature which allows my site's members to enter a url in the form of myWebsite/membersName and be forwarded to their homepage which until adding the vanity URL feature would have been in the form of myWebsite/member-profile.php?member_id=123456

Everything works fine except for the fact that if the URL points to a directory such as myWebsite/someDirectory I get redirected to the error page specified in my .htaccess file.

I'm a PHP Programmer but I'm not too familiar with RewriteRules or their conditions. Below I've pasted my entire .htaccess file from my Linux server's root directory. Can someone please help me figure out what the problem is?

```
SuPHP_ConfigPath /home/helcupor/public_html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#for files, append .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#for vanity urls redirect to url2id.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ url2id.php?vanityName=$1 [L]

AuthUserFile "/home/helcupor/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"

ErrorDocument 404 /routing.php
#AuthName "/admin/"
```

Comment: I was able to answer my own question... I changed the rewrite conditions for the vanity url to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ url2id.php?vanityName=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this condition under the `#for vanity urls`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

You want to make sure a potential member name isn't an existing resource (directory or file). Otherwise, just serve the resource. Not sure what you were trying to compare with the condition that you have. The `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` var would still be the member name.

Comment: ...I already have a table of reserved names. Thank you so much for such a quick response. I come here like everyday but this is my first time actually posting a question. Thank God for StackOverflow!!!!!!!!!